# Iterate in -hosts line (ansible) with customized variable/in-memory inventory

Tags: python, ansible, inventory

I am writing an ansible script, that configures the environment using a configuration .xml file. This file can be always different (both IP addresses and group names of inventory change), that is why I am looking for the possibility to use a variable in the "-hosts" line in ansible. Pseudo-code would look like:

```
- hosts: main
  var: 
     space = (lookup(.......))

- hosts: item.grouphostserver
  -tasks:

  -name: load docker image
   docker_image:
      name: {item.name}
      path: {item.path} 
   loop: "{{ space }}"
   when: item.name == item.grouphostserver
```

This easy loop thing with condition seems not to work at all... Everything I found till now is that you need to explicitly write the name of a group in a -hosts line. Even the group_names[0] does not function! Will appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

second `hosts` group does not work that way. You need to those items to `hosts group` with module `add_host` ..here is the documentation for that module https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/add_host_module.html

I am not sure how your `space` structured but here is the idea .. if you want a working solution, I need to see how your `space` defined...may be a sample would give a better picture

so here is how this can be done ..

```
- hosts: main
  var: 
     space = (lookup(.......))

  tasks:
  - name: add hosts
    add_host:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      groups: new_hosts_grp
    loop: "{{ space }}"
    when: item.name == item.grouphostserver


- hosts: new_hosts_grp
  tasks:
  - name: load docker image
   docker_image:
      name: {item.name}
      path: {item.path} 
   loop: "{{ space }}"
   when: item.name == item.grouphostserver
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the answer! Yes, I know the add_host module, but still I need to create many groups. And according to the name of this group I should do the jobs on a remote server. The defined name in "hosts" with only one group is not suitable. In -host "group[item.name]" does not work either though :(.

Comment: The solution, which you write: to each Server in a group "new_hosts_group" deploy ALL docker_images. What I need is to every Group (in servers inside) deploy its Dedicated docker_image and do stuff.

Comment: yep, so to make sub groups (or seperate groups), you need to show us how your `space` data structure is defined and also the condition on how you separate them. This seems like a more logic. If you can capture the key points on how you are going to form those subgroups, it would be very helpful to answer. All we have to do is put that logic in `when condition` and use multiple `add_host` to form those groups. Or you can split this big question into multiple questions and ask one by one to get precise answer.

Comment: space data has a form of a list of dictionaries, for example: [{key1:id1, name1:app1, grouphostserver1:group1, ipaddress1:111.222.333.444, pathtobinary1:/path/to/binary}, {key2:id2, name2:app2, grouphostserver2:group2, ipaddress2:222.222.333.444, pathtobinary2:/path/to/binary}, ... ].

Comment: On each hostgroup should be deployed its dedicated application, names of hostsgroup are not known in advance, each group can include different or the same IP addresses. The easiest way to solve this task in Python, Java, etc. would be to write a variable in -hosts: item.grouphostserver and further using the loop and when start applications exactly for this host group (see my initial pseudo-code). But it seams, that Ansible does not tolerate any variables in -hosts line. Am I rigth? Or is there any solution for this problem?